# Clonezilla - restore to different partitiion size?

Tags: imaging, clonezilla, partition

I am using PartedMagic on a liveCD, and specifically am using Clonezilla to mirror a partition so that it can be restored to another drive.

However, the drive I am attempting to restore to is smaller - the original was 250Gig and the target is 240Gig.  Only about 10% of this space was in use.

Can I "shrink" the partition to be restored?  Or is there an option in Clonezilla to do this, that I am simply missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clonezilla cannot restore a larger partition to a drive that does not have the capacity to handle that partition.  Thus if you backup a 200 gig partition, even if it only has 10 gig in used space, you cannot restore that partition to a 100 gig hard drive.

My work around was to use restore the image to a larger capacity drive, then use GParted to resize the restored partition to a smaller size.  Then I did a backup of the smaller partition.  Now I can restore it to whatever size drive I need, and if necessary, just increase the partition size after restore, using GParted or the like.